# saving an UUID in MariaDB for use with Vapor

Tags: swift, mariadb, fluent, vapor

I want to use FluentMySQL in Vapor to save data but I cannot read UUIDs properly.

If I use the UUID() function delivered by MariaDB, everything is fine, but if I Use FluentMySQL, the UUID is scrambled:
(first record: Usage of UUID(), second record: Vapor)

```
MariaDB [someDB]> select * from Poll;
+--------------------------------------+-------+---------+---------+--------+--------+
| id                                   | title | option1 | option2 | votes1 | votes2 |
+--------------------------------------+-------+---------+---------+--------+--------+
| 88a18a58-2fcd-11ea-9f62-e283e8014c79 | test  | bla     | bla     |      0 |      0 |
| 7??/.?E??*_P?v                     | bla   | option1 | option2 |      1 |      2 |
+--------------------------------------+-------+---------+---------+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is my model:

```
import Foundation
import FluentMySQL
import Vapor

struct Poll: Content, MySQLUUIDModel, Migration {
    typealias ID = UUID
    static let entity: String = "Poll"

    var id: UUID?
    var title: String
    var option1: String
    var option2: String
    var votes1: Int
    var votes2: Int
}
```

this is my table:

```
MariaDB [someDB]> describe Poll;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id      | varchar(191) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| title   | varchar(191) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| option1 | varchar(191) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| option2 | varchar(191) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| votes1  | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| votes2  | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But if use Vapor to fetch the data, everything seems to be fine. What am I doing wrong?

Output via curl:

```
curl http://locurl http://localhost:8080/polls/list
[{"option1":"bla","id":"38386131-3861-3538-2D32-6663642D3131","title":"test","option2":"bla","votes1":0,"votes2":0},{"option1":"option1","id":"373F3F2F-2E3F-453F-3F0E-2A5F503F7607","title":"bla","option2":"option2","votes1":1,"votes2":2}]
```

Thank you for helping in advance.

Comment: So, I created a new entry. The UUID generated was "5ECDB258-7B5B-4A80-A7B7-DFA2C6D33ED5" but is shown as "^ͲX{[J???ߢ??>?" in mariadb. Maybe someone knows what went wrong? (I guess it is some type mismatch)

Comment: Looks like one has the hex version, one has the binary version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Vapor to create a `UUID` field itself, it creates one with a data type of `varbinary(16)` not `varchar(191)`. This is consistent with the default format for a UUID field in MariaDB/MySQL.

I assume this is a legacy application with data being created outside Vapor? It looks like you are storing a string representation of a UUID value rather than the underlying binary value. Storing binary values in a `varchar` field only causes problems (as you have discovered) if you assume the values are all printable. However, the mix of string and binary format values in the same column is likely to cause problems.

Comment: No, this is not a legacy application - this is my first try writing back end code (I have an iOS-Dev background). The UUIDs are normally generated by Vapor but I think both should be possible: outside Vapor and by Vapor. I changed the type from varchar(191) to varbinary(16). The output is still "messy" but if I use hex(), MariaDB shows the UUID but it lacks the dashes. Thanks for pointing out the error with the type. Is it usual that values need to be converted if fetched from a DB?

Comment: I now found the solution: as Nick pointed out, the type must be varbinary(16). If one uses MySQL he/she can use bin_to_uuid but MariaDB-Users need to do SELECT   upper(CONCAT(     SUBSTR(HEX(id), 1, 8), '-',     SUBSTR(HEX(id), 9, 4), '-',     SUBSTR(HEX(id), 13, 4), '-',     SUBSTR(HEX(id), 17, 4), '-',     SUBSTR(HEX(id), 21)   )) FROM Poll; but this function will be implemented in MariaDB soon.